# "If your absence does not change anything in the life of someone, then your presence does not matter!"

Tags: logic

Is this statement true, a tautology or false ?

Comment: Logic doesn't study whether propositions are true; it only studies whether conclusions derived from certain propositions are true if the propositions themselves are true. You just gave a conjuction, and ask whether it is true. Logic cannot say anything about that.

Comment: The statement (v1) seems to be grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant is "If your absence doesn't change anything then your presence doesn't matter."  We can further express that as "If a change in state from presence to absence does not represent a significant change, then your presence is not significant," which is very nearly a tautology, a sentence that is true based just of the definition of terms.  Under this interpretation, your example would be incorrect, since the first part doesn't correctly capture the contrast between presence and absence.